# C++ Use Of Undefined Type

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
class Logger {
    public:
    DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(Logger);
    DEFAULT_DESTRUCTOR(Logger);
    NO_DEFAULT_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(Logger);

    bool Init(std::wstring logFileLocation, std::wstring assemblyVersion);
    void Shutdown();

    void const LogMessage(std::wstring message);

    private:
    struct LoggerImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<LoggerImpl> impl; // Error here
};
```

However, when attempting to compile, I get the following errors:

```
// Errors:
// Error    1   error C2027: use of undefined type 'ophRuntime::Logger::LoggerImpl'
// Error    2   error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory
// Warning  3   warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'ophRuntime::Logger::LoggerImpl'; no destructor called    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory
```

`Logger::LoggerImpl` *does* have a definition in the corresponding .cpp file:

```
struct LoggerStream::LoggerStreamImpl {
    LoggerStreamImpl(std::wstring componentName) : componentName(componentName) { }

    const std::wstring componentName;

    NO_DEFAULT_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(LoggerStreamImpl);
};
```

And finally, the definition for those macros:

```
#define NO_DEFAULT_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName)    \
    TypeName(const TypeName&) = delete;         \
    void operator=(const TypeName&) = delete;   \
    TypeName(TypeName&&) = default;             \

#define DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(TypeName) TypeName();

#define DEFAULT_DESTRUCTOR(TypeName) ~TypeName();
```

Comment: You can only instantiate your class if the type of the `unique_ptr` is a complete type. If you're just reinventing PIMPL, maybe [follow this guide](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) and [this one](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A unique pointer's parameter type needs to be a complete type in the translation unit where you instantiate the unique pointer:

```
struct Foo;
std::unique_ptr<Foo> p;   // Error
```

The problem is of course that the unique pointer's destructor cannot be defined without the complete type of `Foo`. If you need some kind of pimpling, you can get around that by delaying the destructor into a separate translation unit:

```
template <typename T> struct Impl
{
    Impl();
    ~Impl();
    std::unique_ptr<T> impl;
};

struct Foo
{
    struct FooImpl;
    Impl<FooImpl> impl;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
}
```

This translation unit compiles, because the destruction of `Foo::impl` is left to the destructor `Impl<FooImpl>::~Impl<FooImpl>`, which is declared (the template class `Impl<FooImpl>` *is* complete), and it's only its *definition* that is not available in the present translation unit.

To stress the point of all this once again: The pimpl construction presented here allows you to place the definition of the class `Foo::FooImpl` into a separate, private translation unit, which consumers of the class `Foo` never get to see. The price of this decoupling is an extra dynamic allocation (in the constructor of `Impl<T>`) and an extra indirection (in the definitions of the member functions of `Foo`, not shown), as well as a lack of inlining of the destructor of `Impl<T>::impl`.

For more details see Herb Sutter's excellent [GotW #101](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/).

Comment: Your first snippet is not an error.  That's exactly how I pImpl every day.

Comment: @uberwulu: It depends on the context. Here is [a demo of what I mean](http://ideone.com/t3q61H). It works if the type is complete in the TU (I'll change the wording), but the point of pimpl is to decouple the TUs.

Answer (score 12):

Declare your destructor in the header and define it in the source file.

in the .h

```
class Logger {
    public:
    Logger();  // default constructor
    ~Logger(); // default destructor

    private:
    struct LoggerImpl;                 // impl forward declaration
    std::unique_ptr<LoggerImpl> impl;  // impl pointer
};
```

in the .cpp

```
// Define the impl structure
struct Logger::LoggerImpl
{

};

// Define the default constructor
Logger::Logger() :impl(std::make_unique<LoggerImpl>())
{

}

// Define the default destructor
Logger::~Logger()
{

}
```

That's it.

In your case, you say `LoggerImpl` is defined in the .cpp like this, but I don't see a definition for `LoggerImpl`, just a definition for `LoggerStreamImpl`.

Comment: your answer is the correct one. It should have been accepted

Comment: @BigLudinski, thanks! You just need to mention that you **must** declare _constructor_ in the source file too